# What is the scope of global variable in this case?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm new to python, so this is probably a dumb question.

Take this sample code:

```
y, z = 1, 2
def all_global():
    global x
    x = y + z

print(x,y,z)
```

As I understand, the `global` statment will declare global var `x`, and the `print` statement should print out `3,2,1`

But I got

```
NameError: global name 'x' is not defined
```

So what does the `global` statement actually do in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the function makes `x` a global, but `x` will only be bound if `all_global()` is actually *called*. Until then, there is no name `x` bound.

In other words, it is not enough to declare `x` a global in a function; all it does is alter what namespace `x` will be set in when the function runs, it will not pre-define the name. What would it be bound *to* in that case?

Calling the function sets `x` and the `print()` call works:

```
>>> y, z = 1, 2
>>> def all_global():
...     global x
...     x = y + z
... 
>>> print(x,y,z)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'x' is not defined
>>> all_global()
>>> print(x,y,z)
3 1 2
```

Comment: great answer, thanks! it seem to be not a good practice since `x` is hidden inside function scope. What is the case this pattern can be used for?

Comment: @jAckOdE: hard to think of a good example right now, but perhaps caching could be one (storing a cached value in globals for a next call).